# Getting business report(Detail page sales & traffic) using MWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Hi everyone just want to ask a few questions about the amazon mws api since I stuck for more than a week now finding a great solution of the problem and also this is my first time to code with amazon product. My question is does MWS API get the business report specially the detail page sales and traffic. As I what I have read in the forums some say that it is not available in MWS API, some say also that there's a way to get it through API. I`m confuse right now how to start it. I was also wondering if I can scrape the page but have problem of the two way factor verification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No. The MWS API does not give you access to that report.

We currently have a sales assistant download it every day and upload it into our system.

1. Go to Amazon Seller Central.
2. Hover over Reports -> Click Business Reports
3. On the left, under By ASIN, click Detail Page Sales and Traffic
4. On the Right Change the From Date and To Date to one of the value needed
5. Click Download -> CSV

Comment: I'm in same shoes as you, which is download it every day and upload it to our system, my question Do you add a date or timestamp to the CSV manual??

Comment: @StevenSmith Yes. We have a tool that knows every day of sessions data is supposed to exist in the DB for each company. The tool lists the missing days (usually just the current day as the sales assistants are pretty good at getting to it every afternoon). Sales assistant choose day they are uploading and then download sessions data for that day by setting the from and to date in seller central. Then in the DB we add the info from the CSV as well as a date and then the identifiers for the company. Then we can report/graph on sessions per week or day, etc.

Comment: Neat, Thank for information. we build own PHP Settlement Report and Dashboards Chart for this amazon seller report. so I wonder about the business report as I am building it new pages on it.